# URL/question number in Android

Tags: support, android-app

I often reference SE questions outside, so the question number is important to me. But I see no way to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the timestamps (bottom right of a post), a menu containing the share button will be presented to you. One of the options given to you should be "copy to clipboard".

[image]

Using that share option will place the post's URL (which contains the post ID) in your clipboard for you to use later.

Comment: Not exactly intuitive, and it leads to a menu for the application to use...  too much hassle

Comment: @vonbrand - Yes, in that "application list" there should be a "copy to clipboard" option. This is actually quite consistent across android apps.

Comment: @Lix The "Copy to clipboard" share intent/option is available if you have Google Drive/Docs installed. While most devices that have Google Play, also have Google Drive installed, there is an outside chance it isn't available.

Comment: @StevenV - Yep, looks like you are correct. I just turned on an old phone I had lying around and indeed the clipboard option is missing... It's still possible to get at the URL if you "share" via almost any other option - in those cases it really isn't intuitive...

Comment: @StevenV, this tablet hasn't got Google Drive installed

Comment: Looks like the open in browser solution is the only sure way here.